# Laravel + Vue.js MPA/SPA hybrid structure suggestions and thoughts

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I thought about the following MPA - SPA hybrid, where I basically treat each page as an SPA, but still reloading pages to transit from one page to another (index.blade.php to posts.blade.php) like the habitual MPA. This methods uses laravel routing, session and auth powerful features to render a blade template which contains a single vue.js component.

Imagine you are at the main page, you will have something like this:

```html
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('content')
<body id="vue_root">
    <page-index data={{ json encoded data from backend }}></page-index>
</body>
@endsection
```

As you can see I pass a json object as a prop to vue component, this prop contains all needed data for vue to render.

When using this approach of treating each page as a component I can use vue.js single files to contain all the markup, logic (vue component methods and style) into a single file which will make it easier for me to test and debug.

I have a single vue.js root instance where I register all page components.

However since I'm using laravel controllers as a backend for retrieving all the data along with blade views I will also have to create vue.js components and laravel blade templates, that sounds like double work to me.

What do you think of this pattern? is it good? any ideas to improve this, should I use inline-templates instead (that way I would not need to make corresponding blade templates and vue.js page components.

Answer (score 0):

> use spa pattern.
>
> in spa only one time your index.blade.php file load then load .vue
>   file
>
> so how example:  this is your index.blade.php file

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('content')
<body id="vue_root">
    <vue-router></vue-router>
</body>
@endsection
```

> this is your hotel.vue file where

```
   list,add,edit,delete functionality
```

> this is your room.vue file where

```
  book room,check room available ,etc. functionality.
```

> now if you click on hotel link then just load hotel.vue file with his functionality
>     and send ajax request to server(hotelcontroller) and get hotel list with response in json ..(not reload whole just reload  element)
>
> if u click in room link then load only room.vue file with his
>   functionality and load room dependency ..(not reload whole just reload
>    element)
>
> using vue-router in vue u can do like this......

for more detail see this [link](https://blog.pusher.com/web-application-laravel-vue-part-4/) and also this [link](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/laravel-vue-single-page-app/)